# How to clear a collection before an object is deleted

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am new to Java Programming and Hashmaps and I have a problem that I need help with.

I have a Hashmap that stores a collection of objects:

```
HashMap<String, Shape> turtleShapes = new HashMap<String, Shape>();
```

I am trying to ensure the turtles shape collection is cleared before the Turtle object is deleted.

How do I go about this?

Comment: 1. Did you try `clear()`? 2. Why do you think you have to clear it?

Comment: In Java objects aren't explicitly deleted, so we may need more info. Is the collection part of the Turtle class? Do shapes hold a reference to the turtle?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `turtleShapes.clear()`.

However, unless you have an unusual use case, you don't need to.  Once the Turtle object is deleted or goes out of scope, the garbage collector will take care of clearing and removing all the things it uses.